# How do I hyperlink from a PDF file to a specific page in a PPT file

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint 2010 file saved as a PowerPoint Macro-enabled show (.ppsm) file.  I have a hyperlink on a particular page of the PPSM and I've linked it to a PDF file.  Great, it all works.

Now I need to put a hyperlink in the PDF file that will jump me back to the specific page in the PPSM, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  The information in another thread says to add "#15" (the page number) to the filename, but the link seems to put the entire file path.  I also get an error that this is not a valid file name.  I want to be able to just store the files together in the same directory and have them find each other with the file name, not the whole path.

All assistance gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the slide show and link to a PDF file, the show is still running and sitting on the slide you linked from.

All you need to add to the PDF is a link that closes the PDF or possibly quits Acrobat/Reader altogether.

- Open the PDF in Acrobat, add a link, choose Custom Link, click Next.
- In Link Properties dialog box, go to the Actions tab
- Select Action:  Execute a menu item.
- Click Add to get a list of available menu items, choose File, Close
  or File, Exit.

If you need to return to some other page than the one you started on in PPT, it gets a bit trickier.